# Do we have $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\delta(b)$ implies $\Delta(cd)=\Delta(c)\Delta(d)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hopf-algebras

Assume that $B$ is an algebra which is also a coalgebras (we do not assume that $B$ is a bialgebra: we do not assume $\Delta(cd)=\Delta(c)\Delta(d)$). Assume that $A$ is $B$-comodule algebra. Then we have a map $\delta: A \to B \otimes A$ which satisfies $(1 \otimes \delta)\delta = (\Delta \otimes 1)\delta$, where $\Delta: B \to B \otimes B$ is the comultiplication on $B$. Suppose that for all $a,b \in A$, we have $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\delta(b)$. Do we have $\Delta(cd)=\Delta(c)\Delta(d)$ for all $c, d \in B$?

Let $a,b \in A$ and $\delta(a)=a_{(1)} \otimes a_{(2)}$, $\delta(b)=b_{(1)} \otimes b_{(2)}$. Then 
\begin{align}
(1 \otimes \delta)\delta(ab) & = (1 \otimes \delta)(\delta(a)\delta(b)) \\
& = (1 \otimes \delta)(a_{(1)}b_{(1)} \otimes a_{(2)} b_{(2)}) \\
& = a_{(1)}b_{(1)} \otimes \delta(a_{(2)}b_{(2)}) \\
& = a_{(1)}b_{(1)} \otimes \delta(a_{(2)})\delta(b_{(2)}) \\
& = (a_{(1)} \otimes \delta(b_{(1)}))(a_{(2)} \otimes \delta(b_{(2)})) \\
& = ((1 \otimes \delta)\delta(a))((1 \otimes \delta)\delta(b)) \\
& = ((\Delta \otimes 1)\delta(a))((\Delta \otimes 1)\delta(b)) \\
& = (\Delta(a_{(1)}) \otimes a_{(2)})(\Delta(b_{(1)}) \otimes b_{(2)}) \\
& = ( \Delta(a_{(1)}) \Delta(b_{(1)}) ) \otimes a_{(2)}b_{(2)}. \quad (1)
\end{align}
On the other hand,
\begin{align}
(1 \otimes \delta)\delta(ab) & = (\Delta \otimes 1)\delta(ab) \\
& = (\Delta \otimes 1)(\delta(a)\delta(b)) \\
& = (\Delta \otimes 1)(a_{(1)}b_{(1)} \otimes a_{(2)} b_{(2)}) \\
& = \Delta(a_{(1)}b_{(1)}) \otimes a_{(2)} b_{(2)}. \quad (2)
\end{align}
By $(1)$ and $(2)$, do we have $\Delta(cd)=\Delta(c)\Delta(d)$ for all $c,d \in B$? Thank you very much.

Edit: assume that $B$ is an algebra which is also a coalgebras (but not necessarily bialgebra). Assume that $A$ is $B$-comodule algebra.

Comment: What does "$ab$" mean? Are $A$ and $B$ actually bialgebras? Anyway I don't see why that would be true, at least not with some sort of unitality condition: you could just take $\delta = 0$ and get a $B$-coalgebra no matter what $\Delta$ is.

Comment: I second the concern that you are assuming the existence of a multiplication, something that doesn't exist if $A$ and $B$ are just co-algebras.  But I'm also curious about your definition of $B$-coalgeba.  Nowhere do you make use of $A$'s comultiplication, you just have that $A$ is a co-module of $B$.  I feel like you want to use $\delta$ as a comultiplication, but it isn't quite.  It seems to me like your definition should probably be that you have a map of coalgebras $A\to B$ (dual to the definition of $R\to S$ making $S$ into an $R$-algebra).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, thank you very much. I added that assume that $A, B$ are also algebras in the last line of the post.

Comment: @Aaron, thank you very much. Yes, we only need the condition that $A$ is a comodule algebra.

Comment: "$B$-coalgebra" means "$B$-comodule algebra", right? And $A$ and $B$ are bialgebras?

Comment: @darijgrinberg, thank you very much. Yes, $A$ is a $B$-comodule algebra. I have edited the post. But we do not assume that $A, B$ are bialgebras in the beginning.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I don't know whether $\delta(ab)=\delta(a)\delta(b)$ implies that $B$ is a bialgebra or not (that is $\Delta(cd)=\Delta(c)\Delta(d)$ for all $c,d \in B$).

Comment: OK. But $A$ can be the zero ring. It then becomes a $B$-comodule algebra in an obvious way, but clearly this cannot say anything about $B$. So the literal answer to your question should be a "No". On the other hand, it may be worth looking for weak assumptions under which the answer can be "Yes", such as the existence of an algebra homomorphism from $A$ to $B$ which interacts with the structures nicely (whatever this means).

Comment: As Darij's comment shows, the equality of (1) and (2) does not necessary tell you anything about the equality of each left tensorand in your sum. What you get from the equation is a set of equations based on the decomposition of $a_{(2)}b_{(2)}$ into a basis for $B$ (assuming these are all over a field). A second problem that you might encounter is that $A$ is actually a comodule algebra over a subcoalgebra of $B$ (the $a_{(1)}, b_{(1)}$ would then not exhaust all of $B$.)